# Is there some way to make sure that the raw_input is only non-numeric?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make sure that the user enters the input in the correct format and i do know how to make sure its numeric input but i dont understand how to make sure its not numeric input.

```
x = raw_input('What is your name? ')
y = raw_input('What is your age? ')
try:
    something_to_make_sure_its_not_numeric(x)
    int(y)
    print "Hello {0}, You look very handsome for someone who is {1}.".format(x, y)
except:
    print('please enter input in correct format')
```

y question is that is there some function in python like int() that makes sure that it only has letters.

Comment: You simply don't need such a function. Remove that `something_to...`, and it'll work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also `isdigit()` function with `string` to check whether string is numeric or not. To check whether it is non-numeric, simply use `not` with the condition

```
>>> 'xyx'.isdigit()
False
>>> '123'.isdigit()
True

# Now check output with "not"
>>> not 'xyx'.isdigit()
True
>>> not '123'.isdigit()
False
```

It will be good idea to create your custom function to achieve this using `isdigit()`

```
def is_non_numeric(num_str):
    return not num_str.isdigit()

# Example
>>> is_non_numeric('123')
False
>>> is_non_numeric('xyz')
True
```

Comment: my question is that is there some function that does the opposite and makes sure there are no numbers.

Comment: @AbdullahBilal: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Check if its a digit, and take the not of it

```
if x.isdigit():
           print_error
else:
```

Or use

```
x.isnumeric()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=single%20line%20mode#re.VERBOSE), this allow you to check if a string contain for example a digit:

```
import re
string = "626dsqd"
test = re.search("\d", string)
if test:
  print('please enter input in correct format')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following expression return `True` only of all the letters are non-digits:

```
all(not s.isdigit() for s in x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions to do that:

```
import re
tester = re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]*$', x)
if tester:
    print x
else:
    print 'Incorrect input'
```

If the return of the match method is `None` then your input does not satisfy your Regular Expression rule. In the example above it only verify if is a single string but you can change your re rule to match naything you want.

You can consult the documentation in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more information about re.